# I deleted 'Apple Development IOS Push Services' from the keychain > login, how do I add it back

Tags: apple-push-notifications, keychain

My Push Notifications certificate expired and so I was trying to remember how to generate a new one.

In the process I completely deleted the Keychain section entitled :

Apple Development IOS Push Services and
Apple Distribution IOS Push Services

If you look at the screen shot you will not see these sections under the Certificates > Login keychain.

So when I try to add the certificate to the keychain (by double clicking on it on my desktop) nothing seems to happen.  I assumed that double clicking would create these sections but obviously not.

So I assume I need to add them back in manually.

If this is what I need to do I do not know how to do it and have not found an explanation anywhere.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the solution, basically I deleted all push certificates.

I deleted the signingcertifcate as well.

Recreated the signing certificate.

Recreated the Push certificate

Downloaded it.

Double clicked it into Keychain > Certifcates > Login

and voila, there was the Apple certificate with my private key tucked underneath it.

Then generated my p12 no problem.